# Labels layout in div

Tags: css, html, label

```
<div id="combobox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="tag3"
        name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag3')"/>DialogProc</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="tag2"
        name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag2')"/>fds</label><br/>
</div>
```

I'm using `div` as a container for the checkboxes and their labels. I'm using `<br/>` to position one below another. Is there any way to have the same layout without using `<br/>` (css)?

Comment: You should associate label and form element with for and id attributes, even with implicit labels like you're using [H44: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44)

Comment: @FelipeAls Why exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
#combobox label {
    display:block;
}
```

then remove `<br />` tags

Comment: Simple, works. No additional html tags required. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Better practice would be to separate them by `<p>` elements instead:

```
<p><label for="tag 3"><input type="checkbox" id="tag3"
        name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag3')"/>DialogProc</label></p>

<p><label for="tag2"><input type="checkbox" id="tag2"
        name="checkbox" onclick="toggleTag('tag2')"/>fds</label></p>
```

Also note that it is advisable to give the labels a for attribute to associate them with an input for multiple reasons (e.g. [**accessibility**](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44)). You'd use `<label for="tag3">` for the label for your first `<input type="checkbox" id="tag3">` for example.

If you wanted to reduce the margins caused by using `<p>` elements, then you'd just apply some basic CSS rules to them, e.g.

```
p {
  margin:0px;
}
```

---

[**Here's a jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JqjhG/)

Comment: `p` tag adds a lot of space (margins) around the checkboxes which is something I don't want.

Comment: @NPS Target the <p> elements and remove any unwanted margins in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
//css
#combobox label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```